# ZF2 detach listener from EventManager

Tags: php, zend-framework2, listener

Implementing a new ZF2 app I found myself struggling with the EventManager. In the application module I created an `AuthenticationListener` and a `NotifierListener`. The first checks for proper authentication on users and the second displays custom messages addressed to the logged user.

Now I'm creating a new module that dispatches xml files to export. I want to keep the `AuthenticationListener` but detach the `NotifierListener` to avoid `E_NOTIFY` errors. The problem is that after reading blogs/source code/documentation (pretty poor) and pulling my hair out I'm unable to understand how to detach the listener mentioned above.

#### Application module.php

```
public function onBootstrap($e)
{
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

    $authListener = new AuthenticationListener();
    $authListener->attach($eventManager);

    $notifyListener = new NotifyListener();
    $notifyListener->attach($eventManager);
}
```

#### New module.php

```
public function onBootstrap($e)
{
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

    // ... $eventmanager->detach('NotifyListener');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to make your listener a service

Since it requires no constructor params, it's invokable, so set it in the invokables array

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'NotifyListener' => 'FQCN\To\NotifyListener',
        ),
    );
}
```

Fetch it from the service manager instead of creating a new instance directly in your bootstrap

```
public function onBootstrap($e)
{
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

    $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

    $notifyListener = $sm->get('NotifyListener')
    $notifyListener->attach($eventManager);
}
```

Anywhere you want to detach it, you just need to be able to get at the ServiceManager

```
 // in any ServiceLocator aware class
 $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
 $eventManager = $sm->get('Application')->getEventManager();
 $notifyListener = $sm->get('NotifyListener');
 $notifyListener->detach($eventManager);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I was looking for. Seems that `ServiceManager` is the swiss army knive of the framework

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path. The only thing that you need to do is to call `detach()` on your `NotifyListener` and not on the `EvenManager`. The example bellow comes from the Zend Framework manual for the `EventManager`.

link: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.event-manager.event-manager.html#examples

```
use Zend\Cache\Cache;
use Zend\EventManager\EventCollection;
use Zend\EventManager\ListenerAggregateInterface;
use Zend\EventManager\EventInterface;

class CacheListener implements ListenerAggregateInterface
{
    protected $cache;

    protected $listeners = array();

    public function __construct(Cache $cache)
    {
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }

    public function attach(EventCollection $events)
    {
        $this->listeners[] = $events->attach('get.pre', array($this, 'load'), 100);
        $this->listeners[] = $events->attach('get.post', array($this, 'save'), -100);
    }

    public function detach(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        foreach ($this->listeners as $index => $listener) {
            if ($events->detach($listener)) {
                unset($this->listeners[$index]);
            }
        }
    }

    public function load(EventInterface $e)
    {
        // some code to load
    }

    public function save(EventInterface $e)
    {
        // some code to save 
    }
}
```

This example illustrates very well how to prepare a listener (e.g. `AuthenticationListener`) implementing `ListenerAggregateInterface`.

Assuming the same situation as with your `Module` object:

```
public function onBootstrap($e)
{
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $cacheListener = new CacheListener($cache);
    $cacheListener->detach($eventManager);
}
```

So, assuming your `NotifyListener` implements `ListenerAggregateInterface` or simply has a `detach()` method you can write your `onBootstrap()` method to detach the listener  like this:

```
public function onBootstrap($e)
{
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $notifyListener = new NotifyListener();
    $notifyListener->detach($eventManager);
}
```

Hope this helps, feedback will be appreciated :)

Stoyan

Comment: In one of my tests I did the same you did without success. I thought that the problem was that `NotifyListener` was a new object with empty attributes (the detach method won't iterate). Having seen your answer takes me to @crisp implementation: Use the ServiceManager to get a "persistant" listener that can be detached later. Thanks for your time