# ZF2 Remove anonymous function from event manager

Tags: events, zend-framework2

In my module's `onBootstrap` function I have attached an anonymous function that is hooking into the `dispatch.error` event (for logging purposes):

```
$eventManager->attach('dispatch.error', function($e) {
    //Code here
});
```

I am now setting up Unit Tests and do not want the logging function to run on test requests.

How do I remove this anonymous function from the event manager?

From the [documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.event-manager.event-manager.html#zend-event-manager-event-manager-methods-attach):

> #### attach
>
> [snip]
>
> The method returns an instance of Zend\Stdlib\CallbackHandler; this
>   value can later be passed to detach() if desired.

and

> #### detach
>
> [snip]
>
> Scans all listeners, and detaches any that match $listener so that they will no longer be triggered.

I have therefore altered my `attach` to:

```
$logCallBack = $eventManager->attach('...
```

To what do I save the callback to so that I can remove it in my unit test?

```
$this->getApplication()->getEventManager()->detach(???);
```

Comment: As a stop-gap I have got `$_SERVER['logCallBack'] = $logCallBack;` and `$this->getApplication()->getEventManager()->detach($_SERVER['logCallBack']);`, but this feels very hacky. Is there a method of doing this using the sharedmanager or something?

Comment: When performing your unit tests you shouldn't bootstrap all your modules.

Comment: I wrote this answer a long time ago, the cleanest solution is to refactor your anonymous function as an invokable (a plain old php class with an `__invoke()` method will suffice) and add it to the service manager -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668060/zf2-detach-listener-from-eventmanager/15668756#15668756

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added to the callback to the `$_SERVER` global variable:

```
$logCallBack = $eventManager->attach(['dispatch.error', 'render.error'], function($e) {
    //...
}
$_SERVER['logCallBack'] = $logCallBack;
```

Then where I want to unregister them:

```
$callBacks = $_SERVER['logCallBack'];
if(!is_array($callBacks)) {
    $callBacks = [$callBacks];
}
foreach($callBacks as $callback) {
    $this->getApplication()->getEventManager()->detach($callback);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign the handler returned and later use it to detach it

```
$callBackHandler = $eventManager->attach('dispatch.error', function($e) {
    //Code here
});

$eventManager->detach($callBackHandler);`
```

Comment: Yes, I've got that far. The event manager is attaching the function in my module bootstrap file, and I want to detach it in my test controller. How do I store the call back handler from the bootstrap so I can retrieve it elsewhere in my application?

Comment: @Richard, got your point, I had solved this type of issues by adding parameters in config files (under config folder) like testing = true, this configuration data is available through out the application and based on the true or false condition you can attach events

Comment: One simple option could be to add a reference to the Mvc Event with  `$mvcEvent->setParam('callbackHandler', $callbackHandler);` and then later fetch it within the controller using `$this-getMvcEvent()->getParam('callbackHandler');`. Otherwise move the attaching of the event to the controller factory and only attach it when needed.